# Testing FileSaver in Angular 5

Tags: angular, mocking, karma-jasmine, spy

I have imported file-saver in angular 5 application, when I am executing test cases it is giving following error:

```
TypeError: FileSaver.saveAs is not a function

Spec.ts:
import FileSaver from 'file-saver';

.ts
import FileSaver from 'file-saver';
FileSaver.saveAs(blob, filename);
```

How to mock filesaver in test cases.

Comment: print out FileSaver with console.log and check if saveAs function exist into its prototype

Comment: This could be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44686077/how-to-use-jest-to-test-file-download/44692287#44692287

Comment: @RadonirinaMaminiaina It is "undefined" when I console FileSaver. I am new to Angular 2 Testing, could you please let me know how I can get FileSaver in Spec.ts

Comment: Try this it's working for me. "import { saveAs } from 'file-saver/FileSaver';"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This works in Angular 7, so I'm guessing it will work in NG5. The first thing is to import FileSaver using the 'as' syntax in both the component and the spec:

```
import * as FileSaver from 'file-saver';
```

Then in the spec beforeEach:

```
spyOn(FileSaver, 'saveAs').and.stub();
```

Comment: This seems to have (suddenly) stopped working for me as a mechanism to stub saveAs method. Anyone else observing something similar?