# vitest react write-excel-file: how to test FileSaver.saveAs (download file)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-testing-library, vitest

i try to write a test for my react component that displays a button, and when clicked generates a xlsx file and offers to download.
for this i use these tools:

- react
- vitest
- [write-excel-file](https://gitlab.com/catamphetamine/write-excel-file)
- FileSaver

for this i found
[How to use Jest to test file download?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44686077/how-to-use-jest-to-test-file-download)

and tried to translate this jest example to my vitest enviroment:

```js
// ...
import FileSaver from "file-saver";
vi.mock("file-saver", () => {
  return {
    default: { saveAs: vi.fn() },
    saveAs: vi.fn(),
  };
});

global.Blob = function (content, options) {
  return { content, options };
};

// ...
```

but i get

```js
FAIL  src/MyExample/index.test.jsx > MyExample > check template download AssertionError: 
expected "spy" to be called at least once  ❯ src/MyExample/index.test.jsx:29:30
     27|     await user.click(btn);
     28| 
     29|     expect(FileSaver.saveAs).toHaveBeenCalled();
       |                              ^
     30|     expect(FileSaver.saveAs).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
     31|       {
```

i have no idea if my basic concept can work at all..
i thought that with this mock i replace the global FileSaver lib..
but it seems this is not the case..
i am a bit lost how to track this done and would like to learn too..
i already extracted the saveAs part from the write-excel-file library to my own component so that it is a bit easier for me to understand what is going on..
without success currently.

**What is the correct way / best practice to setup such a test case?**

my full example at [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/romantic-frost-xfxs3m?file=%2Fsrc%2FMyExample%2Findex.jsx%3A39%2C24&layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt78ys1f00082067blb3yr76%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B63.07996789879317%252C36.92003210120683%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt78ys1f00032067jkaxutan%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt78ys1f000520670z4agbxk%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt78ys1f00072067yscqmdop%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B81.14524755625564%252C18.85475244374436%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clt78ys1f00032067jkaxutan%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt78ys1f00032067jkaxutan%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clthp4s8q00022067t664oqm3%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522initialSelections%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522startLineNumber%2522%253A39%252C%2522startColumn%2522%253A24%252C%2522endLineNumber%2522%253A39%252C%2522endColumn%2522%253A24%257D%255D%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252FMyExample%252Findex.jsx%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clthp4s8q00022067t664oqm3%2522%257D%252C%2522clt78ys1f00072067yscqmdop%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt78ys1f00072067yscqmdop%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clthp1h5v00gr2067p1e9tntx%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522UNASSIGNED_PORT%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A3001%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clthp1h5v00gr2067p1e9tntx%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%2522clt78ys1f000520670z4agbxk%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt78ys1f000520670z4agbxk%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt92y2kj019w206743l0gd9w%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TERMINAL%2522%252C%2522shellId%2522%253A%2522clt930hmc001gdhiph9qvfof3%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt93354d01y02067f83jr09o%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TERMINAL%2522%252C%2522shellId%2522%253A%2522clt93357v001jdhip84i2gzy9%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clt93354d01y02067f83jr09o%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D)

my component looks like this

```
import * as React from "react";
import { Button } from "@mui/material";

import writeXlsxFile from "write-excel-file";

export const MyExample = () => {
    const exampleData = [
        {
            forename: "Diana",
            surname: "Umlauft",
            email: "Diana.Umlauft@gmail.com",
        },
        {
            forename: "Jana",
            surname: "Friedmann",
            email: "Jana_Friedmann@gmail.com",
        },
    ];

    const columnsDefinition = [
        {
            column: "forename",
            value: (person) => person.forename,
            type: String,
            width: 15,
        },
        {
            column: "surname",
            value: (person) => person.surname,
            type: String,
            width: 15,
        },
        {
            column: "email",
            value: (person) => person.email,
            type: String,
            width: 30,
        },
    ];

    async function handleDownloadExampleXLSX(event) {
        console.log("handleDownloadExampleXLSX");
        try {
            const xlsxBlob = await writeXlsxFile(exampleData, {
                schema: columnsDefinition,
                // https://gitlab.com/catamphetamine/write-excel-file#browser
                // when no fileName is given results in blob
                fileName: `testFile.xlsx`,
            });
            //console.log("xlsxBlob", xlsxBlob);
            // saveAs(xlsxBlob, `testFile.xlsx`);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }

    return (
        <>
            <Button onClick={handleDownloadExampleXLSX}>
                Download Example
            </Button>
        </>
    );
};

export default MyExample;
```

and my test file

```
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import userEvent from "@testing-library/user-event";

import MyExample from ".";

// based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44686077/how-to-use-jest-to-test-file-download
import FileSaver from "file-saver";
vi.mock("file-saver", () => {
  return {
    default: { saveAs: vi.fn() },
    saveAs: vi.fn(),
  };
});

global.Blob = function (content, options) {
  return { content, options };
};

describe("MyExample", () => {
  test("check template download", async () => {
    const user = userEvent.setup();
    const { container } = render(<MyExample />);
    const btn = screen.getByText(/Download/i, {
      selector: "button",
    });
    expect(btn).toBeInTheDocument();
    await user.click(btn);

    expect(FileSaver.saveAs).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(FileSaver.saveAs).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
      {
        size: 5531,
        options: {
          type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
        },
      },
      "testFile.xlsx",
    );
  });
});
```